# How to use variable in Laravel Query Builder with if variable is not null

Tags: laravel, query-builder

Hi I have a situation where I want

```
$first_name = $request->first_name;
$last_name = $request->last_name;

$customers = Customer::where('first_name','=',$first_name)
    ->where('last_name','=',$last_name **OR $last_name <> NULL**)
    ->get();
```

I want `where` clause to be implemented only if the input `$last_name` is not blank.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

An example

```php
$first_name = $request->input('first_name');
 
$customers = Customer::when($first_name, function ($query, $first_name) {
                    $query->where('first_name', $first_name);
                })
                ->get();
```

`when` will add `where` condition when the `first_name` is not `NULL` or `false`

I hope this helps you

Comment: Excellent, Mohamed Gamal Eidin you are a star, I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$customers = Customer::where('first_name',$first_name)
    ->where(function ($q) use($last_name) {
    if ($last_name) {
       $q->where('last_name', $last_name);
    }
    })->get();
```